# CheckBox .text has & in but it is NOT displayed

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox

I allow the user to enter the text they want into a checkbox, and i save it, and redraw the checkbox to the screen with there text in the text field.

When I debug through it the Text field has the text in it 'blar& blar'

But on the display the '&' does not appear.

I cannot think of anything else to try.

Comment: It would be easy if you provide the code snippet.

Comment: If you add the code snippet, you'll get more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the & character that was disappearing, and by setting

```
UseMnemonic(false)
```

this means all & are drawn to the screen, and no shortcut characters are in use.

but CheckBoxX which is what i am using doesn't have this, they just added the & shortcuts with no way to turn off, so for this I currently need to detect if a user puts in an & and add another & to make it display, and if they delete the & delete the other & with it.

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand is a special character to specify which character is used as a shortcut. Try to put the & before a printable character like "a&b" and you will see "ab" with the b being highlighted when you press ALT to view shortcuts.

Escape a single & by replacing it with a double & (&&) which will result in a single & being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're drawing it, but the '&' character is a mnemonic and must be esacaped by doubling it, i.e. `&&`.  Try holding the `Alt` key and you may see an underline below the following character, depending on your system settings.